# Dynamically access properties in custom namespaces

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Given this:

```
public namespace foo;
foo var bar:String = "baz";
```

We can access the property "bar" like so:

```
var ns:Namespace = foo;
trace(ns::["bar"]);
```

This doesnt work however:

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("foo");
trace(ns::["bar"]);
```

It gives me the following error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property foo::bar not found on MyClass and there is no default value.

On further inspection of the foo namespace I can see (in the debugger) that the URI is in the format {package}:{type}/{name}. If I try to replicate this by doing the following:

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace(getQualifiedClassName(this).replace("::", ":") + "/foo");
trace(ns::["bar"]);
```

(drumroll)

Still no dice.

Additionally I've tried the following combinations without luck:

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace(null, getQualifiedClassName(this).replace("::", ":") + "/foo");
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("", getQualifiedClassName(this).replace("::", ":") + "/foo");
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to get access to namespaced members like this? I don't have compile time access to the namespace, but I can look up it's uri (and prefix) dynamically at run time.

Comment: Tried to find an answer for you, but no luck.  Even tried using `use namespace ns;` but there is the same issue.  Hope you find an answer.  +1 for a good question too.

Comment: Thanks for the effort sberry2A, appreciate it! I was up most of last night trying to figure this one out. I have one more thing to check before I officially give up and that is to see what a disassembler tells me about the byte code. I have found nothing worthwhile in Adobe's docs about this. Again, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:**
Ok the problem here is that when you create a namespace the compiler create it with the flag package internal, or you have no way in as3 to create a namespace with different access flag (public, protected,...)

So if your namespace is declared public you can get it using the function [getDefinition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#getDefinition%28%29).

Here an example of function that parse your uri and give you back your namespace whereever it is declared in a file or in a class

```
package XXX {
 public namespace foo;
}
```

or

```
package YYY {
 class XXX {
  public namespace foo2;
 }
}
```

Here an example of a function that give you the namespace from the uri

```
    public function getNamespaceFromURI(uri:String, domain:ApplicationDomain = null):Namespace {
        if(domain == null) domain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

        var tmp:Array = uri.split("/");
        var ns:Namespace = null;
        var pkg:String = tmp[0].replace(":", ".");
        if(tmp.length == 1) {
            // namespace declared in a file
            ns = domain.getDefinition(pkg) as Namespace;
        } else {
            // namespace inside a class
            var cls:Class = domain.getDefinition(pkg) as Class;
            if(cls) {
                ns = cls[tmp[1]] as Namespace;
            }
        }
        return ns;
    }
```

Usage :

```
var ns:namespace = getNamespaceFromURI("YYY:foo");
// or
var ns:namespace = getNamespaceFromURI("YYY:XXX/foo2");
```

**Edit:**
Ok i missread you have a proplem with a dynamic Namespace name not dynamic property name :
So you can access to your created namespace by a static call to your namespace name from the class where it is defined:

```
class X {
 public namespace foo;
}  

var ns:Namespace=X['foo'];
```

So for your example it's:

```
public namespace foo;
foo var bar:String = "baz";

var ns:Namespace=MyClass['foo'];
trace(ns::['bar'])
```

i have updated the wonderfl example : http://wonderfl.net/c/7M9O

You can create a new [QName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/QName.html) with your custom namespace and your dynamic name, then access the property with this[myQName] :

```
var ns:Namespace=foo;
var qn:QName=new QName(foo, 'bar');
trace(this[qn]);
```

Here the live example on wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/7M9O

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I might have been unclear. Thing is, I have no access to the namespace what so ever. The only thing I have is it's uri and a random object which has a property defined in this namespace. The problem is that Flash fails with an error when I try to access the property, given a dynamically create namespace instance. I hope that clears things up a bit, if not, let me know!

Comment: Very cool find Patrick, thanks a lot for the help! Sorry it took so long to accept, things just got delayed.